# Weird Markdown rendering glitch

Tags: support, markdown-rendering

I just made an edit to [Convert Python escaped Unicode sequences to UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46080224), which should appear as "removed during grace period" in the edit log. I added a newline before and after the fenced code block, and then removed those newlines again.

Unfortunately, I didn't think to get a screenshot; but before the edits, the code block was not rendering properly - it showed the code as two separate inline code spans. I can't fathom a reason for this, especially since the edit log is now convinced that I haven't actually changed the source - I can't roll it back now because the "revisions are identical".

Comment: You may have seen a browser cache? But there are times where the SO cache/snapshot rendering of a version was erroneously not actually what the text renders after changes to markdown software. An edit causes a new rendering per new markdown. (Consistent with this, last edit was in 2017.) (Multiple posts of mine had quote blocks made invisible by new markdown software.)

Comment: Related: [We're switching to CommonMark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348746/241919) (Jun 2020): "*[...]  if we detected that a post would look differently when rendered with the new CommonMark renderer during the migration, we wouldn't save a new version of this post as part of the migration. This way, all posts continue to look the same when being viewed. However, once someone comes in and edits it, it will be rendered using the new CommonMark renderer and this might cause the post to look slightly different than what we had before. [...].*"

Comment: It happens almost all the time in this case, making the editor feel crazy as if they saw something that did not happen :)